# Should I choose CRA or Next.js for the following use case

Tags: architecture, create-react-app, next.js

For my next project I plan to have a login page and most of the content behind that. But the login page will have a lot of information about the website which I need to be very SEO optimized.

Should I use CRA or Next.js for this type of project? Would it be overkill to use Next.js for this and e.g. react-helmet would be enough? Or is there a compromise?

Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`CRA` is pretty enough for this use-case as you can put SEO information to the `public/index.html` file.

Next.js is definitely overkilling if you don't want to use its most important feature which is `SSR`. Since all other pages of your app is protected and the user must login, I don't think `nextjs` helps you there.